# Palettes and Notebook Windows misbehaving

Tags: windows, palettes

I have updated to version 11.3 of Mathematica, and am now getting a bizarre problem with the palettes and some of my notebook files. The contents are shrunk relative to the window size. See below.
[image: Example Palette Error]

[image: Example Notebook Error]

If I change the zoom level (bottom left), the problem just scales up. The action of the mouse cursor seems displaced from the actual location of the mouse cursor, as though the contents of the window were correct. For example, if I place the cursor where a particular palette element SHOULD be, the tooltip for that element pops up.

Help?

Comment: Have you contacted WRI Support?

Comment: Yes. Have not heard back yet, so was hoping someone here might have some insight.

Comment: Maybe, runtimes of Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable packages go wrong, check to uninstall them at programs in control panel, download from here https://www.itechtics.com/microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-versions-direct-download-links/ and reinstall them. Meanwhile check the resolution setting of the display, especially `enabe ClearType` and `reset text-scaling level` see https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/turn-off-or-on-clear-type-text-in-windows-10.html https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/2-ways-to-set-text-scaling-level-in-windows-10.html.

Comment: run `sfc /SCANNOW`  in  `Administrator` role to fix `OS` files and  the `Program Compatibility Troubleshooter` to dectect the correct application setting.